# Check for duplicates in the table before inserting data into SQL Server with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, insert, sql-server-2000

I have got 3 columns in the table, I need to check the email field before insertion of new row, so if the email exist, it should not insert that row. Do I have to go through 2 queries to achieve that, so for instance first check :

```
Select count(*) FROM PRODUCT WHERE email = @email
```

AND THEN RUN AN INSERT

```
Insert INTO PRODUCT (....) VALUES (....)
```

Or is there any better way to achieve that ,

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an `INSERT` statement that checks for the condition, and only inserts something, if it doesn't already exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Product WHERE email = @email)
   INSERT INTO dbo.Product(list of columns)
   VALUES(list of values)
```

Answer (score 1):

As `marc_s` mentioned you may use a *conditional insert* into. On the other hand, using a **unique constraint** on your email column may be very helpful too!

Just think of the possibility to insert data without your application. There would be no rule to avoid the same email!

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
   xxx int NOT NULL,
   xxx xxx xxx,
   UNIQUE (email)
)
```

Just google for [alter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)/[create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) table(s) with [unique constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420.aspx)!